# react native server response data format

Tags: react-native

Among the data coming from the server as a response, the time comes as follows: Dec 1, 2021 12:07:32 PM

I want to use the above format as 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'. How should I convert it?

new Date('Dec 1, 2021 12:07:32 PM') =>  Date { NaN }
moment('Dec 1, 2021 12:07:32 PM').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss') => Invalid date

Answer (score 0):

please do:

```
let date = new Date(dateServer)
date = moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
console.log(date);
```